# liclipse + git + mylyn no branch or commit message

Tags: liclipse

I'm testing LiClipse as a replacement for Eclipse and I have problems getting mylyn to work correctly. It used to pre-fill a new branch name and a commit message from an active task. I cannot get it to work with either LiClipse 3.6 or 4.0. Is this a limitation of JGit?
I do have mylyn preferences set to **Automatically create and manage with task context**

Comment: Weird, there should be no difference from LiClipse to Eclipse in that area... are you using the same workspace on both? (if not, have you shared your project as a git project on the workspace used for LiClipse?)

Comment: I did share the workspace, tried a fresh one etc. two different machines. It might be the jira connector that is messing it up but in theory the connector shouldn matter. So you are saying that it should work with JGit. I will try a fresh install again. That was a very convenient feature that I really miss now. If it works on your end it means I must have done something incorrectly. Cheers.